# Scaling down image with Hermite-resize creates thin black line out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, image, image-resizing

I have to scale down images and turn them into jpegs in a browser. For this i have been using a javascript resize function called [Hermite-resize](https://github.com/viliusle/Hermite-resize)

This works great. After re-sizing a few hundred images I have noticed something odd happens once every while. With some images a thin black line appears at the bottom of the scaled down jpeg image.

[image: Normal image and one with unwanted black line]

I thought this might be due to a transparent line being rendered in the scaled down version. After converting to jpeg, the line then becomes black since jpegs turn no background into a black background.

However if i put a white background behind the image before rendering it as a jpeg, then the problem still remains.

If anyone has an idea on what creates this, or how to fix it, i would much appreciate it.

A jsfiddle to clarify what i mean:

```
canvas.getContext("2d").fillStyle = '#FFF';
canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, W2, H2);
canvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(img2, 0, 0);
document.getElementById("imageid").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gt4r54zr/1/

I'm not sure if it's related but if i set the transparency to full (255) in the Hermite script, then the same black line appears as well:

```
data2[x2 + 3] = 255;// Original value: gx_a / weights_alpha;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3osq1s1w/3/

Comment: Does this only happen at precise pixel values?

Comment: Excellent question invot. This is actually the case. For the image in the example i put all the pixel values in a pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/C43FM9k8 ). I don't see much of a pattern in it though. Although i don't really understand how, rphv's answer does seem to solve my problem so i am happy :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `resample_hermite()` calculates these ratios:

```
var ratio_w_half = Math.ceil(ratio_w/2);
var ratio_h_half = Math.ceil(ratio_h/2);
```

which are eventually used to determine the dimensions of the re-sized image. Note the `Math.ceil`, which rounds `(ratio_h/2)` to the next greatest integer. It appears the black line is being rendered in those cases where the mantissa (i.e., everything to the right the decimal point) of `(ratio_h/2)` is less than `0.5`. In these cases, the calculated height of the image is one pixel too large, and there's no data to fill in these pixels.

Changing

```
var ratio_h_half = Math.ceil(ratio_h/2);
```

to

```
var ratio_h_half = Math.round(ratio_h/2);
```

seems to fix the problem in your example.

Comment: Thank you rphv!! Although i have trouble understanding how, your answer does seem to solve my problem. I tried it for all the troubling pixel heights of this example image, and none caused a problem.  I tried looking at the mantissa but i didn't see the pattern you described. I might have done it wrong though. (If you like you can find the values at http://pastebin.com/C43FM9k8 )

Comment: Glad to help. Your data does show the pattern I identified - let me clarify. Consider `(Original height / new height) / 2`: in all cases, the [mantissa](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html) (also *significand*, or "the part of the number to the right of the decimal point") is less than `0.5`. This means that `Math.round()` and `Math.ceil()` will return different values - for example, `Math.round(4.1666666667) = 4`, but `Math.ceil(4.1666666667) = 5`. In these cases, the calculated size of the resized image is a little bit too large, and the extra space gets filled in with the black line.

Comment: Thank you rphv for further elaborating on this. I understand the rounding difference and how it could cause this effect. This doesn't happen for all the values with a mantissa that's less than 0.5 though. I guess there's another factor involved. However, the whole calculation in the code is a little over my head. I have tried to understand what's going on, but that in itself may have been a mistake ;). For now i'm just really happy my pictures render properly :D. Thank you for that!